# Set Default Printer in Google Cloud Printer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-print

Working on google cloud printing.

```
 var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
 gadget.setPrintDocument("text/html", InvoiceNumber, response);
 gadget.openPrintDialog();
```

Is there some way to select default printer from code. Like use printer id or something.

Above code open a modal popup listed all printers.
But I don't want to list the printer in modal popup.

I want to assign a printer id to set a default printer. Which directly print my document.